# C++ Setting a private class member with function after the object is initialized via a constructor

Tags: c++, function, class, reference, member

I am trying to set a private class member after I have created the object with a constructor. This constructor set a bunch of public members but doesn't touch the private member.

```
class Tower {
  std::vector<Tower> jtowers;
public:
  Double_t E;
  Double_t Et;

void SetJTowers( std::vector<Tower> );
std::vector<Tower> GetJTowers() { return jtowers; }

Tower ();
Tower (TLorentzVector,std::vector<Double_t>);   //For jTowers
Tower (TLorentzVector,std::vector<Double_t>,std::pair<bool,bool>); //For gTowers
Tower (TLorentzVector,std::vector<Double_t>,std::pair<bool,bool>,std::vector<Tower>); //For seed gTowers
};
```

The constructor looks like this:

```
Tower::Tower (TLorentzVector FourVec,
              std::vector<Double_t> otherTowerInfo,
              std::pair<bool,bool> SeedRho_info) {
  E = FourVec.E();
  Et = FourVec.Et();
};

void Tower::SetJTowers (std::vector<Tower> constJTowers) {
  jtowers = constJTowers;
};
```

I then call a function that accepts a reference to a Tower object, does some fun stuff, and then attempts to set the jtowers member.

```
void AngularResolution :: ConstituentJTowers ( Tower& gT ) {
  // Find constituent jTowers
  std::vector<Tower> constJTowers;
  // code to fill constJTowers

  std::cout << constJTowers.size() << std::endl;  // This will a nonzero size
  gT.SetJTowers(constJTowers);
  std::cout << gT.GetJTowers().size() << std::endl;  // As will this

}
```

But when I attempt to check the contents of gT.GetJTowers() later in my code, I still find that it is empty, as if the original object is not being modified.

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: Please pass vectors by reference unless you absolutely want to make a copy.

Comment: **Warning:  data structure endless cycle.** Your `Tower` consists of a vector of `Tower`, which contains a vector of `Tower`.  This may be unsafe.  Separate containers from contents (two separate classes).

Comment: Thanks for the useful tips! I will make these changes.

Comment: Classes may not contain a `std::` container of themselves in Standard C++ (although there are some proposals to allow this in future versions). Trying it might get you bizarre results.  There are `boost` containers that are specifically written to allow this.

Comment: Try to reduce the code to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).   Then, if the answer doesn't present itself, post all the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bypass the `private` access of data members, you have to:

- define *setter* functions
- or change the access to `public`.

The reason behind `private` is to prevent access to data members by external entities.

One school of thought is to provide "setter" interfaces that change the variable.  This allows external entities a method for changing data.  Should the data change to something else, the interface will still be intact, but the implementation would change; thus saving changes to all entities that use the interface.

The other school of thought is to make the data members `public`.  This allows for external entities to directly access the data members.  If the data members change, type or location, all entities that directly access them will need change.

Think first.  Why did you want to violate the encapsulation and data hiding principles?  Is there another method or design so you don't have to break the data hiding?